# Need help centering navigation bar with a logo inline

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to center my navigation bar but every way I have tried so far results with either the navigation bar not centered or it is centered but the links aren't in one line. I would also like to keep the logo in line with the navigation bar but floating left. I tried adding a container class and a nav id but I don't think that did anything. Please Help!

Here is my html:

```
<DOCTYPE html!>
  <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HCstyle.css">
    <title>Hockey Corner</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img class="logo" src="images/Hockey Corner logo real png.png" alt="Hockey Corner logo">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="nav">
        <div class="wrap">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="link.html">Our Sponsers</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And here is my css:

```
img.logo{
  float:left;
  width:10%;
  padding-left:5%;
}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:right;
}
li{
  display:inline-block;
}
li a{
  display:block;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:14px 16px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
li a:hover{
  background-color:#34495E;
}
body{
  background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url("images/Background1.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.nav{
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
}
.container{
  text-align:center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex` property will solve your problem. Learn more [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Working code: https://codepen.io/Sahero/pen/rzmVjN

Comment: Now the Our Sponsors link isn't becoming highlighted when you hover over it.

Comment: Please Help Me! Thank You

Comment: It is getting highlighted when you hover.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your CSS Code .nav to #nav.

There are a lot of way to make located your logo.

I'd like to recommend display:flex.

You can find easy about flex.

Comment: This is almost a partial answer. It would have been better if you can show your flex idea with a fiddle example. The first part about the CSS change is ok.

Comment: @Paul T Thank you for your comment!